# consider virtualenv packages before PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a setup configuration which I call from a single command, let say

```
source mysetup.sh
```

this configures tons of things: gcc-compiler, python executable (version, ...), ..., `PATH` including curstom library, and `PYTHONPATH`. In this way I can use a consistent environment and I also have access to non-standard python packages, as numpy (from `PYTHONPATH`). *I can't change `mysetup.sh`*.

Now, I want to use additional python packages or other versions, but I don't have root access, and I would like to avoid to use `pip --user` so I am using virtualenv. The problem is that if I do something like that:

```
virtualenv -p `which python` my_virtual_env
source my_virtual_env/activate.sh
pip install numpy, tqdm
python
import numpy, tqdm
print numpy.__file__, tqdm.__file__
```

I see that numpy is still coming from one of the directory listed in `PYTHONPATH`, while tqdm is coming from `my_virtual_env` (since it is available only there). If I look at `import sys; sys.path` I see that the directory from `PYTHONPATH` are included *before* the ones from virtualenv and this is the root of my problems. I want that python first try to look at `my_virtual_env` packages, and only after to the `PYTHONPATH`, but still I don't want to get rid of `PYTHONPATH` since there are stuff I need (so I can't just do `export PYTHONPATH=""`).

So: how can I have python looking first into the virtual env and only after to `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Would `export PYTHONPATH="my_virtual_env/site_packages;$PYTHONPATH"` work?

Comment: it seems too simple, looking at `sys.path` I see several more directories added by virtualenv

Comment: I have the exact same issue but this seems to break things for me. When I do this and the call `pip3` I get `AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag' ` Did you find any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky way you could solve this within python:

```
import sys
import os
user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
for path in user_paths:
   sys.path.remove(path)
for path in user_paths:
   sys.path.append(path)
```

I would also like to see a better method, but that should work!

Comment: I don't want to change my code. I want to fix my environment